# Reprojecting geotiff data and plotting with Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray, map-projections, rasterio

I have a geotiff and a data array with the same shapes. The data array is auxiliary data of the geotiff. The x and y coordinates are the size of the geotiff coordinates, but the data array has no projection. I am trying to project the dataarray with the information from the geotiff.

My idea was:

1. Make a new xarray data set from the above
2. Reproject the new data set (to be able to plot it later on with a third data set on top)

The issues I have:

Using `xarr.rio.reproject()` is very smart, but my new data set needs a crs, which it do not have. I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pyproj
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import rioxarray as rio
from rasterio.warp import transform


xarr = xr.open_rasterio('my_geotif.tif')
ds   = xr.open_dataset('my_dataarray.h5')
 
# Projection information
proj_tiff = xarr.crs
wgs84_epsg = 'epsg:4326'
proj_stereo = 'epsg:3995'
print(proj_tiff)
```

Original projection:

```
+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs=True
```

```
### Making the new data set with coordinates from tiff_file and data from dataarray
ds_new = xr.DataArray(ds.classification, coords={"y": xarr.y, "x": xarr.x}, dims=['y', 'x'])
ds_new.attrs = ds.attrs

# Adding CRS information
ds_new['crs'] = 0
ds_new['crs'].attrs = xarr.rio.crs


## closing used datasets
xarr.close()
ds.close()

## Reprojecting
ds_reproj = ds.rio.reproject(proj_stereo)
```

I get the error message:

```
  File "/g5/procdata/skr/anaconda3/envs/pygmt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rioxarray/rioxarray.py", line 1169, in reproject
    raise MissingCRS(
rioxarray.exceptions.MissingCRS: CRS not found. Please set the CRS with 'set_crs()' or 'write_crs()'. Data variable: classification
```

I have tried `'set_crs()` and `write_crs()`, but then I get: `AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute`

Any idea of what to do? It is probably simple, but I have tried so much by now, and nothing seams to work.

Comment: You were close. It's `ds.rio.set_crs()` instead of just `ds.set_crs()`. See also https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/crs_management.html#Setting-the-CRS-of-the-Dataset.